# Using ServiceStack external service within MVC app

Tags: c#, servicestack

I've setup a basic ServiceStack service that provides a centralised data hub for some complex reports.

We have a few different web apps that I want to (somehow) call on this service to get the required data and go on to display reports/graphs etc etc based on that information.

What I'm unclear on is how I actually 'get at' the ServiceStack data in C# as it is running as a completely separate website. (ie; our MVC app, which was created 2 years ago, has no link to ServiceStack at all just now).

I can see how I would be able to call via AJAX; but a requirement I have is being able to, in some instances, manipulate this data in C# directly.

Do I add a service reference like regular SOAP services? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using the C# JsonServiceClient that ships with ServiceStack?

Comment: Are you saying this is the method I should be using to interact with the service? I'm aware of it's existence but am unclear if it is the preferred method for doing this. This would mean adding ServiceStack to every project that intends to utilise the data service, would it not?

Comment: The accepted answer is pretty much where I was heading with that.  You'll basically have to take a dependency in your client apps if you want easy access to SS services from a .NET client.  FWIW - I've also successfully used RestSharp before; but the SS service clients are preferable.

Comment: Also might be worth noting that SS v3 ships the service clients in a different package - ServiceStack.Common I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best (and recommended) way to consume ServiceStack services from a .NET client is to use [ServiceStack's .NET Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client).

The [NuGet package that contains the Service Clients](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Client) is:

```
Install-Package ServiceStack.Client
```

It's only dependencies are:

- ServiceStack.Interfaces
- ServiceStack.Text

For the least dependency you can consume Services with [ServiceStack's Http Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils) which is apart of ServiceStack.Text and has no dependencies, i.e:

```
Install-Package ServiceStack.Text
```

Also worth noting as ServiceStack just sends plain JSON/XML responses over HTTP you can use any .NET HTTP Client.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this. By using the client, do I remove the need to have the DTO classes in my consuming app? I'm wondering how I will deserialise if I don't have the object structure in my project (they're on the service-side).

Comment: It's [recommended that your DTO's be in it's own separate project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Physical-project-structure) so it can be shared with clients without forcing additional dependencies and you get a end-to-end typed API without code-gen. Your DTO's should only need to reference `ServiceStack.Interfaces` i.e. ServiceStack's impl and dep-free interfaces dll. Note: if you want you to avoid dependencies, you can just copy the source files into your client project.